# NetSuite show custom transaction body fields in sublist

Tags: netsuite

I added a transaction body field to show on Sales Order.
I have a subtab named "Tab 1".
I want to create a sublist named "Sublist 1" and put it in "Tab 1"
And I want to add that transaction body field I created to put in that sublist.
I tried to custom transaction form, but I couldn't
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create **sublist 1** and show the **transaction body field** as sublist field, in "Tab 1".

So first of all you don't need to create transaction body field for sales order, you should create a custom record containing that field just like **parent child record**.

steps:-

1. Create custom record and name it as you want the **sublist 1**.
2. Add one field and name it what you want for body field.
3. Add one more field named it as relation(it will be connection field) choose

**Field Type**- **List**,

**in List- Select **Transaction****,

**check the checkbox of "Record is Parent"** (That will be in right side will all checkboxes).

Under **Display tab** - Choose the **Parent Subtab- Tab 1**(What you have already created).

**Sublist 1 will be visible as sublist under Tab 1 with body field**.

if any thing else you are looking for elaborate your question.

Thanks.